# * not interpreted in ftp, lftp?

Tags: ftp, lftp

I'd been seeing that `*` isn't interpreted on ftp or lftp. Suppose I want to change a directory from current to say `./japan`

In ftp> of lftp>, if I give:

```
$ cd jap*
```

it would show this error:

```
No such file or directory
```

So, I'm forced to give the complete name:

```
$ cd japan
```

#### EDIT #1

@thomas, @gold: Thank you for your valuable information. As `*` isn't interpreted with all commands (like `cd`), is there any way so that I can get away from typing every time the complete file name.

Comment: You forgot something.

Comment: What are you asking? I don't see a question being asked here...

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing [shell file expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08) with ftp client features. [`lftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp) supports wildcard expansion with the `mput`, `mget` and `mrm` commands.

Comment: To elaborate: the `cd` command in `ftp` is *similar* to the shell's `cd`, but they are not the same, and `ftp` is not a `sh`.

Comment: Do you mean get away *without* typing the complete file name?

Comment: @kurtm Yes you are right. I'm sorry. I am editing the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `lftp` you can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to do path completion similar to the same method used when in a shell such as Bash or Zsh.

If you continue to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> as you type it will complete as much of what matches. You can continue to type additional characters from the results of what's left that matches what you're typed thus far.

#### Example

Initially after connecting to an SFTP server.

```
lftp me@sftpserver:~> pwd
sftp://me@sftpserver/home/me
```

It I type `cd u` and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> one time it will complete this:

```
lftp me@sftpserver:~> cd upload/
```

If I hit it a 2nd time:

```
lftp me@sftpserver:~> cd upload/
2011-07-12/  a/
```

If I type a `2` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> another time it will complete like this:

```
lftp me@sftpserver:~> cd upload/2011-07-12/
```

At which point if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will run the above `cd` command.